# URL Changing with Regular Expression using C#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

ok this is my question.
i have this url

`http://mycountry.county.india.com`

and i want this in return

`MYCOUNTRY.country.india.com`

I have written a using `SPLIT` in C#. But that is bad though it does the job done. Anyone having a better solution in C#?

**ANOTHER EXAMPLE**

For this

`http://my5-pc.in.aaa.com`

i want this in return

`MY5-PC.in.aaa.com`

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/27 you can use relace.Replace by `$1.upper` or something`

Comment: Can you give more than *one* example? Presumably you have more than one URL you need to deal with and it's difficult for us to understand what the actual requirement is when we only have one example to generalize from.

Comment: Do you just want to remove http:// ? or http://www. or any similar scenario ? is mycountry always the first word or is this a variable?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever check for another example in my edited question.

Comment: @MXD remove http:// and the put everything in caps till the first **.** Occurs . N.B. There wont be like www after http in my case and mycountry is always first word and it is not a variable

Comment: I would start with the first part, removing http:// I would do this with [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs) since removing the first 7 characters can give problem if a url is given without http. I would then use MX D's solution for making the first part of the string capitalized.

Comment: @ACroner the url will always be given with http in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove the http:// and capitalize the first word I would refrain from using Regex as this is slow in general. Http:// is always 7 characters long and could easily be removed using a simple string.remove or Substring

```
str.Substring(7, str.Length-7)
str.Remove(0, 7);
```

And as far as it seems you want the word before the first '.' to be capitalized. For that you could use something like

```
int index = str.IndexOf('.');
if(index > 0) {
    string firstWord = str.Substring(0, index);
    str = firstWord.ToUpper + str.Substring(index, str.Length);
}
```